# Can't import Aer from Qiskit

Tags: quantum-computing, qiskit

When running the following code:

```python
from qiskit import Aer
```

I encountered the following error:

```
ImportError
Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[50], line 1
----> 1 from qiskit import Aer

ImportError: cannot import name 'Aer' from 'qiskit'
```

Why is that the case?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aer/blob/main/docs/tutorials/1_aersimulator.ipynb) tutorial, this is the updated way of using qiskit-aer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `qiskit.Aer` object [has been deprecated in Qiskit 1.0](https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/migration-guides/qiskit-1.0-features#aer). You have to install the `qiskit-aer` package like this:

```
pip install qiskit-aer
```

and then simply modify your code into:

```python
from qiskit_aer import Aer
```