Qiskit | ImportError: cannot import name 'Aer' from 'qiskit'
While installing and tried to import Aer, I get an error.
!pip install qiskit

import numpy as np
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, Aer, transpile, assemble
from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram
import random

Any inromation would be highly appreciated.


you probably just need the separate qiskit-aer package

These questions about Aer are popping up every week now. Please search. Qiskit has updated.

Is this the same as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78180575/cant-import-aer-from-qiskit

To fix this issue, install qiskit-aer package by doing pip install qiskit-aer. And then in your code replace:
from qiskit import Aer to from qiskit_aer import Aer
If you have any further problems please include your qiskit version in the question.
